# how to implement auth with congito in react native expo app?

Tags: amazon-web-services, react-native, google-oauth, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

Im building a react native application with expo.
I already created an api with aws apigateway and some lambdas, so the most comfortable way to protect it is with aws cognito.
Now i also want to include google auth and facebook auth.

Should i add amplify to my project just for the authentication, maybe they have a way of not providing the pool id in the client side or something. but mainly it just might be easier to add googel and facebook auth through the amplify console, and after that just add in the aws console- apiGateway the user pool that amplify genereted, just manully adding it to the apiGateway

Or do you guys think i can use something like npm i amazon-cognito-identity-js

thanks a lot,
have a great day

:)

Answer (score 0):

The Expo SDK documentation contains the AuthSession library that handles authentication with OAuth and OpenID Connect providers. There is a guide on integration with AWS Cognito in this link: https://docs.expo.dev/guides/authentication/#cognito. There are also guides for integrating with both Google and Facebook too. If you are already using Expo it would make sense to make use of libraries available for Expo apps.